# Make input fields inline in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make these 3 input fields small (must stay in modal window) and arrange them inline:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Naziv</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
      <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
      <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85g7Y/

Comment: Does [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-forms) work for you? It is the recommended approach in bootstrap to make forms in a nav-bar, which seem pretty inline to me. You may need to play with the mixins if you do not need to use the concrete style names

Comment: no, becouse i use it into modal window

Comment: How about use the mixin for your forum-group div by applying an additional class, or into a specific selector? Is the mixin not appropriate in general? Could you provide the html as it will stand within the modal window (the window's parent elements and etc)

Comment: click http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/36/edit click on pencil icon on the table row to open modal

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the fiddle for your problem. Hope your problem is resolved using the same.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85g7Y/1/

Code:

```
.form-control{
    position:relative !important;
    display:inline !important;
    width:30% !important;
}
```